# Facebook like appears only after reload of the website

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-like

I use the facebook like and share button on my website. However on some pages the button just appears after I refresh the website (F5). I use the following code:

```
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.0";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

And then further down where I want my like and share buttons (this part is in haml):

```
%div.fb-like{"data-href" => "http://www.mywebsite.com#{request.fullpath}", "data-send" => "true", "data-width" => "450", "data-layout" => "button_count", "data-show-faces" => "false", "data-font" => "arial"}
```

When I click on a link and land on any page the buttons do not show up, when I press F5 the buttons show up after the reload.

I use Ruby on Rails 4.0, jQuery and I also use turbolinks with rails (I'm not sure, but this migt be a problem).

Comment: In my case, disabling turbolinks on links to the page solved the problem.  If these buttons are on many pages, need to disable Turbolinks on the entire app.